# Packer Autoinstall with Ubuntu 21.04/21.10 Desktop

Tags: 21.04

I was trying to automate a Packer build of Ubuntu Desktop 21.04 in vSphere with the HCL below. Since then I have found out that this won't work with the desktop images until 21.10 "Impish" at minimum, as discussed here:

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/refreshing-the-ubuntu-desktop-installer/20659/76?u=nathanto

The original question is below to help others.

The key piece is where the boot command defines the `seedfrom`. That seems not to work in the sense that the `user-data` is never loaded. The VM boots, and the `net.ifnames=0` argument from the boot command is applied (interfaces are named `eth0`).

The logic of the boot command is to press `c` to get to the `grub>` prompt, and then the commands are entered as shown in the `boot_command` below.

I see in the `/proc/cmdline` that the boot command is applied properly.

I can see no indication that the `user-data` is loaded though. If I look at the web server shown in the boot command, using Firefox from the booted VM, the `user-data` and `meta-data` files are there and accessible.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to debug this please?

```
source "vsphere-iso" "dev_vm" {
  username            = var.vcenter_username
  password            = var.vcenter_password
  vcenter_server      = var.vcenter_server
  cluster             = var.vcenter_cluster
  datacenter          = var.vcenter_datacenter
  datastore           = var.vcenter_vm_datastore
  guest_os_type       = "ubuntu64Guest"
  insecure_connection = "true"
  iso_checksum        = "sha256:fa95fb748b34d470a7cfa5e3c1c8fa1163e2dc340cd5a60f7ece9dc963ecdf88"
  iso_urls            = ["https://releases.ubuntu.com/21.04/ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso"]
  http_directory      = "./http"

  vm_name             = "dev_vm"
  CPUs                = 2
  RAM                 = 2048
  RAM_reserve_all     = true
  boot_wait           = "3s"
  convert_to_template = false
  boot_command        = [
    "c",
    "linux /casper/vmlinuz --- autoinstall ds='nocloud-net;seedfrom=http://{{.HTTPIP}}:{{.HTTPPort}}/' net.ifnames=0 ",
    "<enter><wait>",
    "initrd /casper/initrd<enter><wait>",
    "boot<enter>"
  ]
  network_adapters {
    network      = "xxx"
    network_card = "e1000"
  }
  storage {
    disk_size             = 40960
    disk_thin_provisioned = true
  }

  ssh_username = "xx"
  ssh_password = "xx"
  ssh_timeout  = "60m"
}

build {
  sources = [
    "source.vsphere-iso.dev_vm"
  ]
...
}
```

Comment: You are using the Desktop iso, but are using an automation technique for _subiquity_, the Server installer.  I do not think the Desktop iso uses _subiquity_ yet.  This discussion suggests there could be a Desktop installer that uses _subiquity_ with the 21.10 release https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/refreshing-the-ubuntu-desktop-installer/20659

Comment: Thank you, I am digging into the 21.10 desktop releases and will report back.

Comment: This *starts* to work in 21.10 as discussed here: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/refreshing-the-ubuntu-desktop-installer/20659/76?u=nathanto